# Upload images to twitter API from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, twitter

I'm attempting to post an image onto the twitter api, v1.1
I've tried just about all the example out there, and nothing seems to be able to post it.
include [Posting images to twitter in Node.js using Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921371/posting-images-to-twitter-in-node-js-using-oauth)

I'm using the oauth library mentioned there, and I also had jsOauth, which I thought I'd give a shot according to https://gist.github.com/lukaszkorecki/1038408

Nothing has worked, and at this point I'm starting to lose hope on whether I can even do this.

```
 function postStatusWithMedia(status, file) {
var err = new Object();
if(fs.existsSync(file) === false) {
    err.message = "File not found :(";
    parseTwitterError(err);
} else {
    var oauth = OAuth(options = {
        "consumerKey": consumer_key,
        "consumerSecret": consumer_secret,
        "accessTokenKey": access_token,
        "accessTokenSecret": access_token_secret
    });

    callbacks = {
                onSuccess : function() {
                    console.log('upload worked!')
                },
                onFailure : function() {
                    console.log('upload failed!');
                    console.dir(arguments);
                }
    },

    uploadData = {
        'status' : status,
        'media' : Base64.encode(fs.readFileSync(file))
    };

        oauth.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',uploadData, callbacks.onSuccess, callbacks.onFailure);

    return false;
}
 }
```

If it can't be done, can you please explain *why*?
Otherwise, anything that could lead me to the right direction would be great.

Comment: can you tell me how many images / day can we add using twitter upload api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var utf8 = require('utf8');

// Encode in UTF-8
status = utf8.encode(status);

var form = new FormData();
form.append('status', status)
form.append('media[]', fs.createReadStream(file));

// Twitter OAuth
form.getLength(function(err, length){
    if (err) {
        return requestCallback(err);
    }
    var oauth = { 
            consumer_key: consumer_key,
            consumer_secret: consumer_secret,
            token: access_token,
            token_secret: access_token_secret
    };
    var r = request.post({url:"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json", oauth:oauth, host: "api.twitter.com", protocol: "https:"}, requestCallback);
    r._form = form;
    r.setHeader('content-length', length);
});

function requestCallback(err, res, body) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("Tweet and Image uploaded successfully!");
    }
}
```

I ended up using `request` and `node-form-data` to manually construct a multipart/form-data request and send it with the status request, `utf8` was for encoding the status into UTF-8, not doing so caused issues with '<3' and other characters.

Comment: {"errors":[{"code":38,"message":"media parameter is missing."}]}

Comment: @MethuzKaewsai-kao You need to wrap this in a function, use file as the file paramater.

Comment: update_with_media is deprecated by twitter use /status update instead of this

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested these code.Its from my colleague.sure the code is working.
Perhaps this will help.

//twitter_update_with_media.js

```
   (function() {
    var fs, path, request, twitter_update_with_media;

    fs = require('fs');

    path = require('path');

    request = require('request');


    twitter_update_with_media = (function() {
        function twitter_update_with_media(auth_settings) {
            this.auth_settings = auth_settings;
            this.api_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json';
        }

        twitter_update_with_media.prototype.post = function(status, imageUrl, callback) {
            var form, r;
            r = request.post(this.api_url, {
                oauth: this.auth_settings
            }, callback);
            form = r.form();
            form.append('status', status);
            return form.append('media[]', request(imageUrl));
        };

        return twitter_update_with_media;

    })();

    module.exports = twitter_update_with_media;
}).call(this);
```

next file
               //upload_to_twitter.js

```
            var tuwm = new twitter_update_with_media({
                consumer_key: TWITTER_OAUTH_KEY,
                consumer_secret: TWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET,
                token: access[0],
                token_secret: access[1]
            });

    media_picture.picture = imageURL;

                if (media_picture.picture) {
                    console.log('with media upload');

                    request.head(media_picture.picture,
                        function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                            var image_size = response.headers['content-length'];
                            if (image_size > 2000000) { // 2mb max upload limit
                                console.log('greater than 2mb');
                                sendMessageWithoutImage(err, req, res, next, twit, wallpost, access);

                            } else {
                                console.log('less than 2mb');
                                console.log('twitter text', content);
                                tuwm.post(content, media_picture.picture, function(err, response) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log('error', err);
                                        return next(err);
                                    }
                                    error_parse = JSON.parse(response.body);
                                    console.log('with media response', response.body);

                                    if (error_parse.errors) {
                                        console.log('have errors', error_parse);
                                        res.json({
                                            status: 500,
                                            info: error_parse.errors[0].code + ' ' + error_parse.errors[0].message

                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        res.json({
                                            status: 200,
                                            info: "OK",
                                            id: response.id
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
```